# How to install Google Cloud DLP on Mac M1?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, module, pip, google-cloud-dlp

I am trying to download Google Cloud DLP on my Mac M1 running macOS Monterey. I am using Python 3.10.4 and pip 22.0.4.

I first tried using `pip install google-cloud-dlp`, but got an error when I went to import it that I have the wrong architecture (arm instead of x86-64 – hence M1 error).

I then uninstalled DLP and followed the advice of a StackOverflow post to download the library directly from GitHub. I did this, navigated to the directory, and ran `sudo python3 setup.py install`.

Now, when I try to import the library, I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [57], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import google.cloud.dlp

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud.dlp'
```

This is odd because when I run `pip list` I get this in the output:

```
google-api-core          2.7.2
google-auth              2.6.6
google-cloud-dlp         3.6.2
googleapis-common-protos 1.56.0
```

Now, when I run `pip install google-cloud-dlp`, I get a bunch of "Requirement already satisfied" messages, yet when I try to import, I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

I have tried importing in Atom, VSCode, and Jupyter-Notebook, and still get a ModuleNotFoundError. I feel dumb asking this question because it seems like it would be an easy fix, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue is that you have multiple python versions installed. Is it possible that the script ran under in a different Python environment than the one used to print the installed versions?

Could you try following these steps?

1. Create virtualenv.

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

2. Install `google-cloud-dlp`.

```
pip install google-cloud-dlp
```

3. Run code.

```
$ python3
>>>import google.cloud.dlp
>>>
```

If you're still having trouble, try the steps on another environment like [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/launching-cloud-shell) to rule out an issue with your specific environment.